# Create and use variables from a file in Python

Tags: python

I'm kind of stumped on an exercise that I'm doing in Python. I have a file with a few lines, and each line has a a name and value.
In this exercise, I need to calculate the mean of said values. The problem I'm having is creating workable variables, separating and creating a list or string for the names only, and same for the values.

Once that's done, it's just a matter of dividing the sum of the values in the value list by the len of the names, I would assume.

So far I have only gotten as far as:

```
f = open("shopping.txt", "r")

for i in f:

    t = i.split()

    print t
```

And I got this output:

```
['TV', '300']
['Radio', '20']
['computer', '500']
['Smartphone', '400']
```

Any advice?

Comment: Well you already have the values in `t`, so what part do you have problem with exactly?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, he wants to create a dict from these objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
cart = {}
combined = 0
with open('shopping.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if len(line) <= 0 or not '=' in line: continue

        key, val = line.split('=',1)
        cart[key] = int(val)
        combined += int(val)
```

The above code will let you know the joint value in one operation loop rather than sum:ing stuff up later, it also lets you work with individual items in your chopping cart like so:

```
print(cart['Radio'])
```

And thus showing only the radio's value

Comment: It keeps giving me key, val = line.split('=',1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Most likely an empty line. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good so far.  After applying `.split()` you will need to convert the elements of the list to `int` using `values = [ int(x) for x in t ]`, then you can sum the elements up using `sum(values)` and divide by the length of the list using `len(values)`.

EDIT:

After your edit I'd propose to just use the second value in each line: `t[1]`, sum those up: `sum = 0` initially, i. e. before the loop, then in the loop: `sum += t[1]`, and after the loop divide that sum by the number of lines used (so you should count the lines using the same technique, i. e. `count = 0` initially and then `count += 1` in each loop iteration.

Comment: After your post's edit I now see that you do _not_ have several values in each line but one value with a leading description.  So my answer does solve a different situation.

Comment: Added an update for the new situation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file has this format:

```
#file
name1 value1
name2 value2
...
namen value2
```

You can compute the **mean** in this way:

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    values = [int(line.strip().split()[1]) for line in f]

print 'mean:', float(sum(values)) / len(values)
```

Comment: @JackMort: I'm really glad to have helped! ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
with open("shopping.txt") as file: # same as 'file = open("shopping.txt")'
        data = file.read().splitlines()
        shopping = {k:int(v) for k, v in [line.split("=") for line in data]}
        file.close()
print shopping
```

**EDIT**
To find the sum:

```
print sum(shopping.values())
```

Comment: it also gives shopping = {k:int(v) for k, v in [line.split("=") for line in data]}
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @JackMort, then use `line.split()` instead of `line.split("=")`.

Just, I've used different file format

Comment: Works good now, thanks :)